# how to add special characters in mongo $regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, regular-language

I want to look for "\r" in a string field I have in mongo, and I fount this, which looks like it works good:

```
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*son.*"}});
```

the problem is that i want to look for "\r" and I can find it, which I know its there, so I just did:

```
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*\r.*"}});
```

and it dosent work, how can I fix this?

example document:

```
{
    "personId" : 1,
    "personName" : "john",
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Rue Neuve 2\\r\\rue Pré-du-Mar \\r ché 1 1003 Lausanne",
        "street" : "",
        "zipCode" : "",
        "streetNumber" : ""
    }
}
```

so my query is:

```
db.users.findOne({"address.city" : {$regex : ".*\r.*"}});
```

also tried:

```
db.users.findOne({"address.city" : {$regex : ".*\\r.*"}});
```

Comment: Try escaping the backslash `\\r`.

Comment: @marekful tried and didnt work unfortunately. updated the question and added example

Answer (score 0):

try

```
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*\\r.*"}});
```

Comment: Can you send a sample of your collection ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you have your .* backwards at the end.  You are looking for a "2." literal followed by any characters as opposed to  what you have at the beginning, .*, saying anything before the literal that isn't a carriage return.  Try to change this to

```
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*\\r*."}});
```

Which says give me "\r" with any non carriage return characters before the literal and any non carriage return characters after the literal.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the way to do it is:

```
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*\\\\.*"}});
```